# issues when handling callback data with merchant API of faucetpay.io

Tags: php, cryptoapi

I am currently configuring my website to utilize faucetpay.io's merchant API from the https://faucetpay.io/merchant where there is also a short documentation, unfortunately not clear enough. I contacted their support, no response as of yet. I have implemented the following in my index.html:

```
<form action="https://faucetpay.io/merchant/webscr" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="merchant_username" value="sanox">
<input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="RCP Webpage - buy 64 spesmilo points">
<input type="hidden" name="amount1" value="0.001">
<input type="hidden" name="currency1" value="USDT">
<input type="hidden" name="callback_url" value="https://example.com/callback.html">
<input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="https://example.com/callback.html">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="https://example.com/index.html">
<input type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-purple" name="submit" value="Buy ₷64">
```

In my callback.html, I have implemented the following:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE);
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
require('res/config.php');
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['app'])) {
    $user = $_SESSION['app'];

// Debugging
var_dump($_POST); // Check the entire POST data

$token = $_POST['token'];
echo "Token: " . $token;

$payment_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://faucetpay.io/merchant/get-payment/" . $token), true);
$token_status = $payment_info['valid'];
$merchant_username = $payment_info['merchant_username'];
$my_username = "sanox";

if ($my_username == $merchant_username && $token_status) {
    // Processing logic when validation is successful
    mysql_query("UPDATE crypto_users SET points = points + 64 WHERE `email` = '$user'");
    echo 'Thank you. Payment processed. ₷64 added to your account!';
} else {
    echo "Invalid payment attempt. TokenID: " . $token;
    echo " Merchant Username: " . $merchant_username;
}
} else {
    die('Please login first!');
}
?>
```

I've noticed that during testing with my other user sanox1, the balance of 0.001 USDT is deducted correctly from his account, and I see the transaction in my merchants account sanox. However, in the output of callback.html, all the variables e.g. $token, $merchant_username etc. appear to be null or empty, I see array(0) { } Token: Invalid payment attempt. TokenID:
Merchant Username: Could you please help me understand why this is happening ? Maybe I don't pass the token correctly? Also I don't quite understand what is the connection between  https://faucetpay.io/merchant and https://faucetpay.io/merchant/get-payment/

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: It appears I can't see the api documentation without a merchant account, so I can't give a very definitive answer. The fact the transaction is recorded and the callback is called is encouraging, but it looks like they are not including the data you expect as POST data.

Comment: Hi Jerry,
thanks for reply. I think the view of their merchant api documentation is visible even if you have no merchant account. It is bacically these two steps :
the form and the IPN callback. This is all they have on their merchant api section.

Comment: I did change   to  <input type="hidden" name="callback_url" value="https://webhook.site/8a707944-340b-4e9a-9076-4f18d4a18ad6">and tested a payment with my other user successfully, and when I open https://webhook.site/8a707944-340b-4e9a-9076-4f18d4a18ad6, I see POST with following parameters : 

token 2b211783a407a1ac6bb0922db3912012d063c662
transaction_id 6dded8d76144eb6bd3e325d5e86e1d841115462b
merchant_username sanox
payer_username sanox1
amount1 0.00100000
currency1 USDT
amount2 0.00100000
currency2 USDT
custom (empty)
exchange_rate 1.00100000

how to do my own callback.php?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// callback.php

// Retrieve the token from the URL parameters
$token = $_POST['token'];

// FaucetPay API endpoint
$apiEndpoint = "https://faucetpay.io/merchant/get-payment/$token";

// Make a GET request to FaucetPay API
$response = file_get_contents($apiEndpoint);

// Check if the request was successful and if the response is valid JSON
if ($response === false) {
    echo "Error fetching data from FaucetPay API.";
} else {
    $data = json_decode($response, true);

    if ($data === null) {
        echo "Error decoding JSON response from FaucetPay API.";
    } else {
        // Process the JSON response
        print_r($data);

        // Check if the payment is valid
        if ($data['valid']) {
            
 

                // Update the database if validation is successful
                $email = 'somemail@mail.com'; // Replace with your actual email field
                 

                // Your database connection code here
                $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

                // Check the connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }

                // Prepare and execute the SQL statement
                $sql = "somesql here";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "Record updated successfully";
                }
            
            
            
 
        } else {
            echo "Invalid payment. Validation failed.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

finally the following callback.php worked for me. I did some testing with https://webhook.site/ as advised by faucetpay's support and then changed from     `<input type="hidden" name="callback_url" value="https://webhook.site/MY_ID">` to `<input type="hidden" name="callback_url" value="https://example.com/callback.php">` in the form